# python json issue with bytes type serializing

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am following a tutorial to build a simple webscraper from a static website, but i get the following TypeError:
TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Here is my code thus far:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

```
url = 'http://ethans_fake_twitter_site.surge.sh/'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
tweetArr = []

for tweet in content.findAll('div', attrs = {'class': 'tweetcontainer'}):
    tweetObject = {
        "author": tweet.find('h2', attrs= {'class': 'author'}).text.encode('utf-8'),
        "date": tweet.find('h5', attrs= {'class': 'dateTime'}).text.encode('utf-8'),
        "content": tweet.find('p', attrs= {'class': 'content'}).text.encode('utf-8'),
        "likes": tweet.find('p', attrs= {'class': 'likes'}).text.encode('utf-8'),
        "shares": tweet.find('p', attrs= {'class': 'shares'}).text.encode('utf-8')
    }
    tweetArr.append(tweetObject)
with open('twitterData.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(tweetArr, outfile)
```

The only thing I can assume is wrong is that the article is using an earlier version of python, but the article is quite recent, so that should't be the case. The code is being executed and the json file is created, but the only data on there is "author:". Sorry if the answer is obvious to some of you, but I'm just starting to learn.

Here's the entire error log:

```
(tutorial-env) C:\Users\afaal\Desktop\python\webscraper>python webscraper.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscraper.py", line 20, in <module>
    json.dump(tweetArr, outfile)
  File "C:\Users\afaal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\afaal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 429, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Users\afaal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\afaal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\afaal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Users\afaal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Why all the `.text.encode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: Stop creating bytes objects and keep the strings?

Comment: @AMC Done. Just following a tutorial, please forward your question to Ethan Jarell from HackerNoon. ;)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga And how exactly would I go about doing that?

Comment: I feel like I was so close, yet so far... How did I not realize that nothing else is done after the `encode()`?!

Comment: @JohnDoe stop doing `.text.encode('utf-8')`... why are you doing that to begin with? EDIT: out of curiosity can you link the tutorial?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/building-a-web-scraper-from-start-to-finish-bb6b95388184

Comment: Removed .text.encode('utf-8') and now I get the following error: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga answered your question and followed your advice to no avail

Comment: @JohnDoe you need to keep the `.text` part. It requires a `str` object. Note `bytes` or whatever custom type your library is using. Honestly, you really need to do some basic research on JSON serialization in Python. This sort of cargo-cult programming is not an effective way to learn anything.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That worked! Will do!

Comment: Create the file with encoding="utf-8", not the individual strings.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out I needed to remove everything after ".text" and also just google "Json serialization" (I only tried to google my specific TypeError and didn't get any conclusive information). The correct code would then be as follows, in case any amateur like myself is having the same problem:

```
url = 'http://ethans_fake_twitter_site.surge.sh/'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
tweetArr = []

for tweet in content.findAll('div', attrs = {'class': 'tweetcontainer'}):
    tweetObject = {
        "author": tweet.find('h2', attrs= {'class': 'author'}).text,
        "date": tweet.find('h5', attrs= {'class': 'dateTime'}).text,
        "content": tweet.find('p', attrs= {'class': 'content'}).text,
        "likes": tweet.find('p', attrs= {'class': 'likes'}).text,
        "shares": tweet.find('p', attrs= {'class': 'shares'}).text
    }
    tweetArr.append(tweetObject)
with open('twitterData.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(tweetArr, outfile)
```

All credit to @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks a lot for clearing this out completely!

Comment: you might want `open('twitterData.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8")`